# how to SELECT and UPDATE query involving two table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

With MYSQL I can insert into a table using a select statement with where clause

```
INSERT INTO Targeted (field1,field2) SELECT field1,field2 FROM Table WHERE id=$id
```

And now i trying to do update with select too...Here is how my table look like

```
 tagged                tags
---------          -------------
fid   tid            id  amount
 1     2              1    0
 1     1              2    0
 2     2              3    0
 3     3              4    0
 3     4
```

How do i select fid from table tagged with specific WHERE clause like fid = 1 Then update table tags with returned result from tagged

```
Input
fid = 1

Desired output
update tags with 1 amount=amount+1
update tags with 2 amount=amount+1
```

I been through some research on SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) here is how my query look like **but its not giving any error or changes too**

```
UPDATE
     tags
SET
     tags.amount = tags.amount+1
FROM
     tags
INNER JOIN     
     tagged
ON     
     tags.id = tagged.tid 
WHERE
     tagged.fid  = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) syntax wrong. In MySql table refs go first and then `SET` clause.

Try

```
UPDATE tags t JOIN tagged d
    ON t.id = d.tid 
   SET t.amount = t.amount + 1
WHERE d.fid  = 1
```

After an update `tags` table will look like

```
| ID | AMOUNT |
---------------
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |
|  3 |      0 |
|  4 |      0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4316/1)** demo